# Docker credentials store on WSL2 without Docker Desktop

Tags: docker, wsl-2

To run Docker directly on WSL2 without using Docker desktop I followed different sources. The steps I performed are very similar to those describe here: https://dev.to/felipecrs/simply-run-docker-on-wsl2-3o8. Docker works, but I still had to configured a credential store so a docker login would work. I tried two approaches:

A) I tried to use **pass as credential store** following https://github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers/issues/102#issuecomment-388974092
'docker login'.... `Login Succeeded`. The auths were added to .docker/config.json, where the credsStore was set to '**pass**'. However, after the successful docker login, the pull command still fails with an authentication error: `Error response from daemon: unauthorized: unauthorized to access repository:...`
It seems like the token is not used for the subsequent command anymore.

B) Trying a less desirable approach, I switched to configuring **wincred.exe as credsStore**

```
~/.docker/config.json

   {
        "credsStore": "wincred.exe"
    }
```

as shown in the Bonus section at the bottom here: https://dev.to/felipecrs/simply-run-docker-on-wsl2-3o8:

```
wincred_version=$(curl -fsSL -o /dev/null -w "%{url_effective}" https://github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers/releases/latest | xargs basename)
    
sudo curl -fL "https://github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers/releases/download/${wincred_version}/docker-credential-wincred-${wincred_version}-$(dpkg
    --print-architecture).zip" | zcat | sudo tee /usr/local/bin/docker-credential-wincred.exe >/dev/null
    
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-credential-wincred.exe
```

This approach works, but strangely every login or pull takes > 1min before the authentication passes successfully and the operation starts.

I would prefer to have a clean Linux-only approach similar to A, but would also be grateful for an explanation / solution to the remaining issue with B.

Comment: wincred_version=$(curl -fsSL -o /dev/null -w "%{url_effective}" https://github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers/releases/latest | xargs basename)
sudo curl -fL \
    "https://github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers/releases/download/${wincred_version}/docker-credential-wincred-${wincred_version}-$(dpkg --print-architecture).zip" |
    zcat | sudo tee /usr/local/bin/docker-credential-wincred.exe >/dev/null
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-credential-wincred.exe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're using `pass`, that means that you needed a GPG key to encrypt the credential store for Docker.

Does your GPG key have a passphrase? Maybe it's trying to request for it but it doesn't know which terminal to use. For encrypting your credentials the passphrase isn't required, since it uses the public-key (so `docker login` won't cause any error) but for decryption it requires the private-key, so it will fail if it isn't able to ask you for the passphrase.

Try setting the `GPG_TTY` in WSL2 to the one that you're currently using for the Docker pull:

```
export GPG_TTY=$(tty)
```

Comment: Marvelous. That was it. If I could double up-vote, I would. Thank you!